# How can I ascertain the proper harvesting/extraction period for birch syrup for a particular region?

Tags: food, trees

My friends and I plan to go on a road trip, to tap and harvest some birch Tree sap/syrup, from a property up in Quesnel, BC. How do I know when is the right time to harvest?

Also; does the time to harvest birch syrup in Quesnel correspond to the time to harvest maple syrup?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sap flow in trees is a result of sap pressure accumulated in the roots during a frost, which is then released when the temperature thaws during the day. Many tree species cannot be harvested because they do not develop high enough sap pressure to bleed ([according to Venerable Trees, Inc.](http://www.venerabletrees.org/sap-flow-in-spring/)).

One [farm in BC reports](http://joybileefarm.com/birch-syrup/) that birch sap is harvested just after maple:

> Birch trees begin to run sap about the time the maple trees are
>   finished. Before the buds swell up and burst into leaves – usually
>   **when the nights are still below freezing but the daytime temperatures
>   are above freezing** – end of February to the middle of March in BC or
>   even into the first part of April, depending on the year.

This is consistent with the [average min/max monthly temperatures for Quesnel, BC:](http://www.myweather2.com/City-Town/Canada/British-Columbia/Quesnel/climate-profile.aspx) [image: Temperature graph for Quesnel, BC]

Interestingly, [Cornell University gives](http://maple.dnr.cornell.edu/produc/sapflow.htm) the same temperature conditions for maple trees as described above for birch, i.e. **when day/night temperatures swing across the freezing point**. I'd suppose birch trees just prefer a bit more warmth.

In particular, the [**University of Alaska Fairbanks**](http://www.uaf.edu/files/ces/publications-db/catalog/hec/FNH-00150.pdf) says birch prefers a daytime temperature consistently above 50 °F. This occurs about mid-April in that region, but earlier for Quesnel as per the graph above.